# Can we remove firebase database node while it is being read

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am having an exception in Firebase Database native layer. I am suspecting that we are deleting the node while we are reading it using the following code.

```
userNotification.on('value', async snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.val()) {
      const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()
      // do something here
      userNotification.remove()
    }
  })
```

Is the above code ok? Or should I move the remove code outside of the on('value') callback?

The exception that I am getting is in the below screenshot:
[image]

Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
Can't modify config objects after they are in use for FIRDatabaseReferences.
-[FIRDatabaseConfig setPersistenceEnabled:]

Comment: *"I am having an exception"* -- and the exception is...?

Comment: Added the exception details

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing the database at the same time will never cause an exception if the code is written correctly.  What you have there is a bad call to enable/disable persistence.  It must be called prior to any other database access is done.

Since you are showing the error on iOS, I'll point you to the Objective-C api for [persistenceEnabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#persistenceenabled), which says:

> Note that this property must be set before creating your first Database reference and only needs to be called once per application.